# Synced TreeSet Cast?

Tags: java, collections, synchronization, treeset

I am using a TreeSet in Java to hold a list of integers:

`TreeSet<Integer> num = new TreeSet<Integer>();`

Since my application has multiple threads, I want to be able to access it *synchronously*. I'm using `Collections.synchronizedSortedSet(num);` and this returns a `Collections$SortedSet`. My problem is that this cannot be cast to a `TreeSet`- it can only be cast to a `SortedSet`. I cannot change the class of the num object, so it *must* be cast to a `TreeSet`.

Does anyone know how I might otherwise cast `Collections$SortedSet` to `TreeSet`, or another method by which I could synchronize this `TreeSet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such implementation, but you can easily make one your on. Just extend `TreeSet`, and override it's methods with synchronized methods.

for example:

```
public class MySyncedTreeSet extends TreeSet {
    @Override
    public synchronized boolean isEmpty() {
        return super.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean contains(Object o) {
        return super.contains(o);
    }

    // and the same for all other methods
}
```

Comment: I figured I would end up having to do that...thanks though!